# Label and user-entered value overlap html

Tags: html, css, label, css-transitions

I added a transition to the label, but when clicked outside of the input, it returns to its original place and conflicts with the input that the user entered. If there is an input in the input, how can I ensure that the label does not move?

This is the html part.

```
                   <div class="input-container input-group mb-3 col-12 mb-4 w-75">
                        <div class="input-group mb-3 col-12 ">
                            <label for="password" class="form-label">Password</label>
                            <span class="input-group-text" id="Password"><i class="bi bi-key"></i></span>
                            <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control"aria-label="Password" aria-describedby="Password">
                            <span class="input-group-text">
                                <i class="bi bi-eye-slash" id="togglePassword"></i>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

And this is the css where I control the transition.

```
.form-label {
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    transform: translate(0, 23px) scale(1);
    transform-origin: top left;
    transition: 200ms cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms;
    color: #6f81a5;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1;
    left: 46px;
    top: -11px;
    z-index: 100;
  }

  .input-container:focus-within label {
    transform: translate(0, 12px) scale(0.8);
    color: #0a53e4;
    padding-top: 5px;
  }
```

Comment: Sorry if this is not directly helpful, but since you are using aria- attributes, I’m assuming that you are interested in rendering your UI more accessible. So here are some remarks on a11y: Currently, `aria-label` is redundant, as you already are already using a proper label with the same text. Kudos for the label (: `aria-labelledby` is referring to an element without any text, so it’s useless. Your visibility toggle is not a button, so also not focusable and it is missing text.

Comment: By animating only :focus-within, any entered text will be covered by the label again, won’t it?